# Editing and retagging to make a duplicate fit?

Tags: discussion, retagging, exact-duplicates

There's a question currently open, but with one vote to close as duplicate.

The [open question](https://superuser.com/questions/181510/how-to-enable-fast-user-switching-in-mac-os-x-10-6-4) is about fast user switching in Mac OS 10.6.4 (aka Snow Leopard).

The [original question](https://superuser.com/questions/76388/leopard-how-to-change-user-without-closing-applications-running) has an answer that does correctly answer the new question, but has "leopard" in the title and is explicitly tagged as `osx-leopard`.

If we simply close the current question, future users might ignore the other because of its title and tag.

Options I see:

- Leave the new one open as an answer for Snow Leopard
- Close the new one and edit the original to either add the Snow Leopard tag or simply remove release specific wording and tags

Comment: I'd vote for the second solution.

Answer (score 4):

I think updating the older question to fit would be the perfect fit - I would have done it at the time if I had the time.

Comment: I updated the older question, since the only answer matches for both, it's acceptable. The new question is closed as duplicate of this older one. Feel free to edit it more if needed.